Should you seasonally decompose TS data before linear regression?
I want to apply the U-MIDAS method which is basically Least Square regression to a cross sectioned time series. Do I need to seasonally decompose my X and Y and should I test for unit root? Some of the papers I read do that and some don't so I do not know what to do? The whole method is odd, but this is what is done by all researchers.

Can you cite those references you mentioned that they recommended to (in-/)excluded seasonality time  component from your TS data before applying LR or OLS? what is the philosophy behind of it?

I thought this is a usual step when dealing with time series data of any kind no matter if applying U-MIDAS or ARIMA.Is it not?
